# We couldn't sign you in. Please try again

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm getting the error `We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.` when I try to login to my custom web app that uses Azure AD. The client secret expired so I figured I could just create a new one and replace it to see if that fixes it. However my current app doesn't seem to have a client secret.

I used a lot of boilerplate code to set this up originally so I don't know what's going on with this to be honest. Below is my Startup.cs file where I pull the client ID and other stuff from the web.config file. Notice a lack of client secret.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    private static string replyUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ReplyUrl"];
    private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = replyUrl
            });
    }

    private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            value = string.Empty;

        if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return value + "/";

        return value;
    }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Or it may be something completely different. After I login it does a bunch of redirects and ends up with the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was accessing the original URL on `http` and not `https` and that was causing an issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! It might be helpful to others if you mark it as answer to make it more discoverable.

Comment: In my case, it was working fine before, suddenly one day I started getting this error. Checked the User Sign in logs and found that the Client Secret had expired. After changing it, I was able to login.